# Handling French special character in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm using utf8_encode || utf8_decode ..., but I'm struggling to handle some special characters (é, è ê ... ,)

I'm using php.

Could someone help?

Comment: Your question isn't very precise. You may first want to check if you're able to put static text on the page. Verify that your editor use UTF-8 encoding and that the page is also served as with `Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8` or use an equivalent `<meta>` tag.

Comment: I a form that get data and a function that save all in a db. When the user put for exemple " d'actualitée" it is saved as "d'actualitÃ© v4"

Comment: If user input is utf-8 I guess there is a mismatch between your data encoding and your database client charset. What sort of db are you using ?

Comment: is mySQL set to save data as UTF-8 (I think its the default anyway) and if you get the result that's garbled in phpMyAdmin then it's the phpMyAdmin's problem. It doesn't use the meta to specify UTF-8 so it displays garbled text. IT should be fine if you echo the results on a webpage with the meta tag saying charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

might wanna use html ascii instead of the actual special char if you having problems with it

http://www.asciitable.com/